# Oracle - all_tables is not complete?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

How come `all_tables` does not show actually contain a list of all the tables?

I can do `select * from blah;` and `desc blah`.
But doing `select * from all_tables where lower(table_name) = 'blah';` returns 0 rows.

blah is not a synonym or view but a table.

Is there a specific stats command that needs to be run so that all the tables that my user can query appear in `all_tables`?

Comment: Does your user have DBA privilege?

Comment: I don't believe you. If you have a table called BLAH and you have rights on it, `select * from all_tables where lower(table_name) = 'blah';` will return a row. So somewhere in your code you have made a mistake. Please review it.

Comment: 'blah' could be a view or synonym.

Comment: Try `select * from all_objects where lower(object_name) = 'blah'` and check the OBJECT_TYPE.

Comment: Do you find the object when you try a `select * from dba_tables`

Comment: I don't have dba_tables access and it is not a view or synonym.

Comment: Are you sure you are querying the right all_tables? Not one that was created by the user you are using?

Comment: Yes, I have not created my own all_tables table.

Comment: What have you done to confirm that blah is not a synonym and not a view?

Comment: one more system table is there `all_objects` try to query `select object_type from all_objects where lower(object_name) = 'blah'` .. first it will give the type of "blah" object in your system ..

Comment: Why do you have the 'lower' clause? Oracle "all_tables" is probably expecting a match on an upper case value.

Comment: @WarrenRox, it's possible, though ill-advised to created cased objects in Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

'BLAH' is probably a synonym that references a table or view of a different name.  You might try the following statement to see what's going on.

```
select owner, object_name, object_type 
    from all_objects 
    where object_name = 'BLAH'
union
select o.owner, o.object_name, o.object_type
    from all_synonyms s, all_objects o
    where synonym_name like 'BLAH'
      and o.owner = s.table_owner
      and o.object_name = s.table_name;
```

I ran it on my system and saw this output (names changed to protect the indigent).

```
OWNER   OBJECT_NAME    OBJECT_TYPE
------- -------------- -----------
PROD    T_BLAH         TABLE
PUBLIC  BLAH           SYNONYM
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a confusion with object name.
Please check in `DBA_OBJECTS` with the object name

> USER_TABLES- tables owned
>
> ALL_TABLES - tables owned, tables owner by other users with access to
>   you
>
> DBA_TABLES - all tables in the database

Answer (score -2):

Try disconnecting and reconnecting your session and see if the result changes.